# Is it possible to create URLs to items on the Apple iTunes store programmatically?

Tags: api, itunes, itunes-store

Is it possible to create URLs direct to items on the Apple iTunes store programmatically?

I have noticed that [last.fm](http://last.fm) and similar sites have links which take the user directly to a part of the iTunes store, such as an album page.

The URL for the link is created by last.fm. Here's an example of such an URL:
http://www.last.fm/affiliate_redirect.php?restype=9&id=3168755&supplier=24

I presume they have some code behind this link, but surely they did not add all of the items manually?

Comment: Do you mean iTunes Store or your own itunes library? Are you on PC or on Mac?

Comment: Thanks Mouviciel, I amended my question regarding the store. The app is a web app, so both mac and PC need to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two aspects.  First, you can get deep links by [programatically searching the App Store](http://www.onemanclapping.org/2009/01/itms-link-generator-api.html):

```
http://www.onemanclapping.org/2009/01/itms-link-generator-api.html
```

Next, you can convert those links to affiliate links using the [LinkShare API](http://brandontreb.com/money-you-might-be-missing-out-on-linkshare-api-integration/):

```
http://brandontreb.com/money-you-might-be-missing-out-on-linkshare-api-integration/
```

[link text](http://www.onemanclapping.org/2009/01/itms-link-generator-api.html)

Answer (score 5):

[This page](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/faq.html) states:

> Linking to iTunes How do I create
>   iTunes links?
>
> Use your affiliate user name and
>   password to log in at
>   [www.linkshare.com](http://www.linkshare.com). On the Create Links
>   page for iTunes, you will find banners
>   and text links. As an affiliate, you
>   also have access to the iTunes RSS
>   feeds and the ability to create direct
>   links to any song, artist, album, or
>   audiobook on iTunes, as well as to
>   iMix playlists, podcasts, and iTunes
>   Essentials.

So that sounds like a "no". Of course there's always the brute force approach of screen-scraping the output of a search engine fed from a list of artist names, or from whatever you want to create a link to ...

Answer (score 2):

A Good thing to remember is that apple use app ID's in the URL structure, if you want to be able to code a link to your app before your app is live you can create the url yourself by going in to itunes connect, finding your app ID and then creating a URL as bellow.

[image: Apple ID from Itunes Connect]

```
http://itunes.apple.com/app/id439244209
```

Answer (score 0):

Programatically we search songs by URLs, this  is code for that link available from itunes API

```
NSString *method=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?term=shakira's+waka+waka&entity=musicVideo"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:method]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    artist=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
url=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    album=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Its a very bad reply to Question. Please give formatted answer that is Readable.